# Strict windows folder content

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I'd like to set some content restrictions for folders in Windows 8.
It's the same as in having library for video, audio or picture content but I'd like to control that there isn't any content or disallowed file types.

Likely, there isn't such a Windows Explorer option but maybe somebody knows software that allows one to do this?

Comment: So you want it to throw an error if for example you try to copy a Video to a folder marked for Audio?

Comment: Warning or error doesn't matter. Any notification would be good